# Ocaml: How to get list of every combinations of permutation of two lists?

Tags: list, ocaml, permutation, combinations

I have two lists, let's say for example :

```
let x = [1;2];;
let y = [true;false];;
```

I want to essentially have a (int*boolean) list list with

```
[[(1,true);(2;false)];[(1,true);(2,true);];[(1,false);(2,true);];[(1,false);(2,false);]]
```

Anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The question is not specified very well as to what exactly is the operation. What about `[(1,true);(1,false)]`? It seems that the operation is not symmetric -- the things in `x` always appear in that order, while the things in `y` can repeat and appear in any order. Maybe it would help if you break it down into two tasks:

1. Every permutation with repetition of the second list
2. Zip every result with the first list

Answer (score 2):

I think nobody is answering because this kinda looks like a homework problem.  I would start by considering just the second elements of all the pairs in your desired result.  I see a pretty regular structure: TF, TT, FT, FF.  It would be a little *more* regular in the order (say) FF, FT, TF, TT.  Anyway once you can make a list of lists that looks like this, it's pretty easy to pair up lists with other lists using functions from the `List` module.

(You might get more answers if you showed some things you tried and explained why they didn't work.)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can consult [List module's document](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html)

Otherwise, just type

```
$ cd `ocamlc -where`
$ less list.mli
```

You may find functions for what you want to do.